# Is it "D.J.," "DJ," or "deejay"?

Tags: slang, abbreviations, music, acronomatopoeia

Should it be *D.J.*, *DJ* or *deejay*?

This is in the context of a person who plays recorded music at a party or club; referring to such a person as a "disk jockey" or "jock" seems hopelessly old-fashioned.

There are three variants in vogue and all are heavily used. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deejay) redirects *deejay* to disc jockey and states it is "also known as *DJ*."  From the [NYT](http://www.nytimes.com/2011/10/24/us/personal-eco-concierges-ease-challenges-of-going-green.html?_r=1) in 2011: "a not-so-green affair with 50 to 80 people at a hot club with an open bar and a hip-hop deejay."  The [same source](http://www.nytimes.com/2012/06/03/opinion/sunday/jonathan-poneman-pumping-gas-in-toledo.html), though, uses a different spelling in another article: "after having spent 30 years as an entertainment industry functionary — as a D.J., promoter and record label exec."

The [Washington Post](http://www.washingtonpost.com/national/bridesmaids-the-hunger-games-fight-for-top-honors-at-mtv-movie-awards/2012/06/03/gJQANOSPBV_story.html) earlier this month wrote: "Martin Solveig will serve as the house *deejay* at the Gibson Amphitheatre show."
Also, many stage names in the music business favor one form, as in DJ Spooky, DJ Jazzy Jeff, DJ Skribble, etc.

Is there a preferred version of the term?

Comment: Interesting [Google Ngram](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=D.J.%2CDJ%2Cdisk+jockey%2Cdisc+jockey%2Cdeejay&year_start=1950&year_end=2005&corpus=15&smoothing=1&share=&direct_url=t1%3B%2CD.J.%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2CDJ%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisk%20jockey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdisc%20jockey%3B%2Cc0%3B.t1%3B%2Cdeejay%3B%2Cc0) of some of the possibilities.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I imagine that the all-lower-case **deejay** is favoured by publications that try to avoid acronyms and initialisms.  Where they are permitted, whether to include or omit the abbreviation marks is a matter of style.

In British English, **deejay** is not used. (Neither is the similar **emcee**.)

Note also that **DJ** is occasionally used informally as an abbreviation for [**dinner jacket**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dinner_jacket)!

Comment: deejay is occasionally used in BE, although I would accept that it is not common. DJ is probably the most common, the confusion with clothing being either easily interpreted in context, or for deliberately confusing people.

Answer (score 5):

Disc/Disk Jockey is abbreviated as "D.J."/"DJ". Nowadays, it's a growing trend to *omit* the dot(.) from abbreviations. Hence, you see both, D.J. and DJ.

According to a [Wikipedia article](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Deejay_%28Jamaican%29),

> "Deejays are not to be confused with disc jockeys from other music genres like hip-hop, where they select and play music."

Answer (score 1):

All are used. It is actually a reference to "Disk Jockey", so D.J. is the most accurate, but we're talking about one of the most informal terms I know of, so I wouldn't be too concerned about "correctness".

Comment: Or is it "Disc Jockey"?